# How write event for drawed shape?

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I drew a circle using this code:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // Create pen.
            Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
            // Create rectangle for ellipse.
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 100);
            // Draw ellipse to screen.
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(blackPen, rect);
        }
```

how can i write a `mouse-over` or `click` event for this circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can assign a click event on the rectangle

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 200);
            Click += Form1_Click;
        }
//associate this method to Click event Form
     private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 100);
            Point cursorPos = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            //you are in rectangle so message display
            if (rect.Contains(cursorPos))
            {                
                MessageBox.Show("in");
            }

        }
```